# Using a variable while defining another variable for a model in django

Tags: python, django

Basically what I want to do is this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_number = models.FloatField()


class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.FloatField(default=self.a.a_number)
```

I understand I can't use self while defining the variables, but is there a workaround for this? What if 'a_number' was a method instead of a variable?

I know i could make a method like this in B:

```
def b(self):
    return self.a.a_number
```

But I need to get the value of 'a_number' right as I create the object in B so this wouldn't work.

Comment: You are trying to set a default from an instance `a` that doesn't exist.

Comment: And even if it did, this still wouldn't work; a default is only applied when the instance is created, at which point the foreign key field `a` would also be blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a [clean() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) to set the default value for `b`.

```
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.FloatField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.b is None:
            self.b = self.a.a_number
```

The Django documentation linked above suggests `clean()` as the way to automatically provide a value for a field:

> ## Model.clean()
>
> This method should be used to provide custom model validation, and to
>   modify attributes on your model if desired. For instance, you could
>   use it to automatically provide a value for a field, or to do
>   validation that requires access to more than a single field:
>
> ```
> (example omitted)
> ```

Remember to call `clean()` before calling `save()` on your model. If you use the Django admin site, then `clean()` is automatically called when an object is created or updated on that site.